# Sitecore ECM E-mail Campaign folder

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore-dms, ecm

I'm using Sitecore 7.2 with ECM 2.1 and I'm curious whether is possible to move E-mail Campaign folder from Home node into Content node?
Whether this will lead to some problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move it to content node and you have to update the "Default Root Parent" field to point content node in /sitecore/system/Modules/E-mail Campaign Manager item.